# Store ajax data in PHP variable

Tags: php, functions, ajax

I made an ajax call to get ID from the dropdown menu, I want to get this data store in variable PHP to make something

ajaxcalls.js

```
    $(".developer_select").on("change",function(event){
        
        var ajaxurl = ajaxcalls_vars.admin_url + 'admin-ajax.php';
        var nonce = jQuery('#wpestate_tab_stats').val();

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action': 'wpestate_load_get_developer_id',
                'developer_id': event.target.value,
                'security': nonce
            },
            success: function(data){
                $(".res_developer_id").val(event.target.value);
                console.log(data) // Output: {developer_id: 5} 5 for example
            }
        })
        
    })
```

in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpestate_load_get_developer_id', 'wpestate_load_get_developer_id' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpestate_load_get_developer_id', 'wpestate_load_get_developer_id' );

function wpestate_load_get_developer_id(){
    global $wpdb;
    $developer = intval($_POST["developer_id"]);

    $arr = array();
    $arr["developer_id"] = $developer;

    $json = json_encode( $arr );

    echo $json;

    $tab_terms      =   array();
    $terms          =   get_terms( 'property_category', array(
                        'hide_empty' => false,
                    ) );
    
    foreach( $terms as $single_term ){
        $args = array(
            'post_type'         =>  'estate_property',
            'author'        =>   $developer,  // Here I want to get data value each select
            'posts_per_page'    =>  -1,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'meta_key'          => 'prop_featured',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'property_category',
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                    'terms'    => $single_term->term_id,
                ),
            ),
            'fields' => 'ids'
           );
          $all_posts = get_posts( $args );
           if( count( $all_posts ) > 0 )
     $tab_terms[ $single_term->term_id ] = array( 'name' => $single_term->name, 'slug' => $single_term->slug, 'count' => count( $all_posts ) );

        }
       foreach($tab_terms as $term){
        
            echo $term['name']; // I want to implement it in HTML div
        } 
    
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Make your php code more concise, I fail to see how the entire php file is relevant to the question.  Also, you can just google "pass data from ajax to php". You will find some good results.

Use post, and in your php file test with something like `if (isset($_POST["JS_VARIABLE_NAME"]))  echo  call_relevant_php_function();`

Comment: Why are you trying to `echo $json;` in the middle and at the end of your PHP function?  You can't echo the output from PHP when the ajax action has `dataType: 'json'` - You have to return a json encoded array.  You should use `wp_send_json($json)` to send your output back to the Ajax function.